# Getting around errors with snap in order to install VSCode

Tags: snap, visual-studio-code

I am following the instructions [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux) to install VSCode, but I get an error on the very first line. It is written at [snapcraft](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-ubuntu) that "If you’re running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus) or later, including Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver), Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish) and Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine), you don’t need to do anything. Snap is already installed and ready to go."

```
error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/code: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory
```

When I try to ping snap with the command "systemctl status snapd.service", I get

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

When I try to check the snap version with "snap version", nothing happens. In fact, that was a lie, for the result is even worse than nothing happening. Ubuntu moves onto the next line, you cannot type any more commands, and I have to press ctrl-C to get out of a silent but deadly infinite loop.

Every time I try to install a line editor, it fails. I couldn't get gedit to work and I couldn't get emacs to work. Ubuntu is quickly becoming a pain to work with, and I'd appreciate if someone could tell me where I'm going wrong in trying to install VSCode.

OS: Windows 10

Ubuntu version: 20.04.1

Comment: You cannot install Snap packages in WSL. You must use a different Virtual Machine host application like VirtualBox or VMWare.

Comment: @user535733 It turns out the solution was even simpler than VirtualBox or VMWare, but I didn't notice until you said it was impossible to use snap. After searching VS Code WSL, I found https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl and followed the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use snap in WSL. Follow the instructions [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl) to install VS Code.